# Transfer software from another Ubuntu

Tags: transfer, copy

I and my friend has Ubuntu. I want to get a software from his lap to my lap. How can I copy the software?
Note: I couldn't download the software from net as the software is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the files in a particular software package with `dpkg -L packagename`. You can find out which package an executable is in by typing `dpkg -S $(type -p executable)`. If you installed "a software" with some method other than `dpkg`, `apt-get`, `synaptic`, etc, you are on your own.